# Possible independence of a generic sentence?

Tags: logic, model-theory

Let the generic sentence $P :$  "$\exists z \in Z \text{ such that }p(z) \text{ is true }$".
In addition $Z$ is recursively enumerable, and  for a given $z_0$ in $Z$,  "$p(z_0)$ or $ \lnot p(z_0)$" is  provable.

If we find $z_0$ such that $p(z_0)$ is true, then the proof of $p(z_0)$ is also a proof of $P$.

**If** $P$ is *independent* (i.e. neither provable nor refutable, for a given system of axioms), then in particular there is no proof of $P$.  So in particular we can't find $z_0$ such that $p(z_0)$ is true (because else there is a proof of $P$).     Then $P$ is false (because $p(z_0)$ is not independent), **contradiction**.

> **Question**: Is it a correct proof that $P$ can't be  independent ?

I don't think so, I think there is a *beginner mistake* but I don't understand where is it.

**Example**: Let $Z$ be the set of all the non-trivial zeros of the Riemann zeta function, and $p(z)$ the proposition "$Re(z)  \neq 1/2$". For a given $z_0$ in $Z$, the sentence "$p(z_0)$ or $ \lnot p(z_0)$" is provable.
So if there is not the *beginner mistake* I'm talking about, then the Riemann hypothesis is not independent.

The purpose of this example is to show that there is certainly the *beginner mistake* I'm talking about, because there is no (yet) a proof that the Riemann hypothesis is not independent (see the MO post: [Can the Riemann hypothesis be independent?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/79685/can-the-riemann-hypothesis-be-undecidable)), so that it's very unlikely that the trivial proof above is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to use a familiar theory, we use $\mathbb{N}$ instead of $Z$.

We need to distinguisish between *completeness* and *decidability*. A theory $T$ is complete if for any sentence $\varphi$ of the appropriate language, one of $\varphi$ or $\lnot\varphi$ is a theorem of $T$. A theory $T$ (over a countable language) is *decidable* if there is an algorithm that, given any sentence $\varphi$, will (ultimately) halt and say yes if $\varphi$ is a theorem of $T$, and will ultimately halt and say no if $\varphi$ is not a theorem of $T$.

Let $T$ be first-order Peano Arithmetic. It turns out that (if the theory is consistent) then $T$ is neither complete nor decidable. The usual proof of the incompleteness of $T$ uses the undecidability of $T$, but the notions are logically distinct.

Your question seems to be about Incompleteness, and not about Undecidability.

Let $\varphi(x)$ be a formula with $x$ as the only variable that has a free occurrence in $\varphi$. Then for every natural number $n$, either $\varphi(\bar{n})$ is true in $\mathbb{N}$, or false in $\mathbb{N}$. Here $\bar{n}$ is the *formal* object $SS\dots S\bar{0}$. But it is convenient to use $n$ instead.

Your argument goes as follows. Suppose that for every $n_0$, one of $\varphi(n_0)$ or $\lnot\varphi(n_0)$ is a theorem of PA.  Suppose moreover that there is no $n_0$ such that $\varphi(n_0)$. Then $\exists z\varphi(z)$ is false in $\mathbb{N}$. That is correct.

Then it looks as if you conclude that $\lnot\exists \varphi(z)$ is a **theorem** of PA. So it looks as if you are concluding (partial) Completeness of PA, for this restricted class of sentences.

That part is not true. If PA is consistent, then there are formulas $\varphi(x)$ of the type you describe such that $\lnot\exists x\varphi(x)$ is not a theorem of PA.

Such formulas can even be constructed from suitably encoded versions of the assertion that the Diophantine equation $P(x_1,\cdots,x_n)=0$ has a solution in the  natural numbers, where $P$ is an explicit, albeit messy, polynomial with integer coefficients.

Comment: If first-order PA is consistent (and it is, I am just writing this for technical correctness) then there are sentences $\phi$ that are true in $\mathbb{N}$ but not provable in PA. Your statement is (informally) correct, but we need to be explicit about the theory that provability refers to. In fact **any** theory $T$ with a recursive set of axioms which has $\mathbb{N}$ as a model has unprovable true sentences.

Comment: If my sentence $P$ is true but unprovable (in a (supposed) consistent system of axioms), and if we find "by chance" $z_0$ such that $p(z_0)$ is provable, why the proof of $p(z_0)$ doesn't give a proof of $P$.

Comment: It does give a proof. The answer said that it is possible for $\exists z \varphi(z)$ to be **false** but for $\lnot\exists z\varphi(z)$ to be nprovable..

Comment: Ok, so for example, if (under ZFC (if consistent)) the Riemann Hypothesis is true, it still can be unprovable, on the other side if $\lnot(RH)$ is true, $\lnot(RH)$ is necessarily provable.

Comment: That is correct, although for RH it is not entirely obvious. One could convince oneself that if a certain root is not on the critical line, then that fact can be numerically verified. Clearer is to use one of the purely number-theoretic assertions equivalent to RH.

Comment: @André Nicolas - I suppose that you are exploiting the fact that "there is a class of statements that are guaranteed to be true if provable in a consistent system $S$ incorporating some basic arithmetic. Suppose $A$ is a *Goldbach-like* statement [i.e.$\Pi$-0-1]. We can then observe that if $A$ is provable in such a system $S$, it is in fact true. For if $A$ is false, it is provable in $S$ that $A$ is false, since this can be shown by a computation applied to a counterexample, and so if $S$ is consistent, it cannot also be provable in $S$ that $A$ is true." 1/2

Comment: ... from Torkel Franzén, *Godel's theorem : an incomplete guide to its use and abuse*, 2005, page 21. 2/2